# Does orthogonality in real imply orthogonality in imaginary term?

Tags: orthogonality

I am not sure about the following statement is true?

Given the complex matrix $A$ of size $m\times n$, i.e., $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$

If for all $v \in \ker A$ (i.e., $Av = 0$) and vector $w \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$,
    $$\operatorname{Re}\langle v,w\rangle = 0 $$ holds,
then $w \in (\ker A)^{\perp}$

To prove this, we need $\operatorname{Im}\langle v,w\rangle =0$.
But currently I can't know how this is derived.
I expect your comment about this.

Comment: I expect Your comments and thoughts in this.

Comment: I have updated my question. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $Av=0$, then $Aiv=0$, so the real part of $\langle\,iv,w\,\rangle$ is zero, but the real part of $\langle\,iv,w\,\rangle$ is (up to sign) the imaginary part of $\langle\,v,w\,\rangle$, so $\langle\,v,w\,\rangle=0$, and we're done.